# limit of multivariable functions plus a difficult problem in continuity

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

At my multivariable calculus class we gave this definition for the limit of a function:

> *Definition:*
>
> Let $ \mathbb{R}^n \supset A $ be a open set , let $f:A \to\mathbb{R}^m $ be a function, let ${\bf x_0}$ be a point of $A$ and ${\bf P}$ a point of $\mathbb{R}^m$.
>
> To say that $f$ has limit $\bf{P}$ at $ {\bf x_0} \in A$,
>
> is difined to mean
>
> $\forall \, \varepsilon>0$, $\exists \,  \delta(\varepsilon)=\delta >0 : ( \forall \, {\bf x} \in A: \left\lVert {\bf x} - {\bf x_0} \right\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n}< \delta \Rightarrow \left\lVert f({\bf x}) - {\bf P} \right\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^m}< \varepsilon  )$

So I have a question. Why the set $A$ has to be open? It seems that the problem is the way that the $ {\bf x}$ will approach the ${\bf x_0}$.

Moreover, in the following problem I had to deal with such a set and continuity

---

**problem:** Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$  with $$ f(x,y)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \sqrt{1-(x^2 +y^2)}  & (x,y) \in \overline{\mathcal{B}}({\bf0},1) \\
   \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{x^2 +y^2-1}} & (x,y) \notin \overline{\mathcal{B}}({\bf0},1)
 \end{array}
\right.$$

Prove that the $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

*(Note that $\overline{\mathcal{B}}({\bf0},1)$ is the Euclidean closed unit ball)*

---

*my thoughts,*

*It is obvious that the function is continuous everywhere except the set* $$\displaystyle \mathcal{S}({\bf 0},1)=\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}=1  \right \} $$

*So we need  to show that $f$ is also continuous for every ${\bf x} \in \mathcal{S}({\bf 0},1)$.*

*But I have no idea how to do it.*

So any hint or a solution would be helpful, moreover it would be appreciated if someone answers my question about the definition of the limit.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition a of limit, the set $A$ does not *have* to be open: The same logical predicate makes sense even if $A$ is not open, and the resulting concept is useful. That said, your instructor/textbook might add extra conditions if it simplified matters for some reason. Here it may be that the ultimate aim is to define differentiability, and for *that* you do need an open set. Perhaps they felt it was better to make one uniform hypothesis, and to let you realize openness isn't required once you understand the definitions solidly.

For your specific function, it's technically helpful to decompose $f$ as $f(x, y) = g(r^{2})$, with $r(x, y) = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ and
$$
g(u) = \begin{cases}
  \sqrt{1 - u^{2}} & |u| \leq 1, \\
  e^{-\frac{1}{u^{2} - 1}} & |u| > 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Your instructor probably has in mind that you'll use known properties of elementary functions. Breaking down your function as indicated will make an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof easier to construct.